# Collapsing boxes (image menu)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website for a friend and he wants an effect on his homepage similar to the one [HubSpot](http://www.hubspot.com/) has on theirs. If you open HubSpot in your browser, the effect I want is just under the main navigation. It is the one with the two images on the left which when hovered change the image on the right. I don't know what the proper term for this effect is.

I am almost finished with the website but my CSS implementation of this HubSpot effect is a little buggy. The left bottom image collapses when the website is visited with my Samsung Galaxy S5, iPhone 5 and Mac Computer with Retina Display. Each image should be exactly half the height of the parent. I would like to achieve exactly the same effect as the one HubSpot has.

I can't figure out why the bottom image on the left side is collapsing. Here is a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dani_ivanov/st7nof0h/embedded/) with my code. I would really appreciate your help!

I think that it has something to do with the high resolution and "Retina" displays because on my simple monitor with 1920x1080 HD resolution the website work just fine without this collapsing issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="row column hOuter">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 hLeftParent columns">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns hLeft1">
                <span>
                    <h3>Workshops</h3>
                    <p>Get creative. Become certified.</p>
                    <a class="btn-transparent" href="#">Learn More</a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns hLeft2">
                <span>
                    <h3>Blog</h3>
                  <p>Coming Soon</p>
                </span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 medium-6 hRight columns">
        <span>
            <h3>Download</h3>
            <p>Get certified and join this new approach to event design!</p>
            <a class="btn-transparent" href="#">Book Now!</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hOuter {
    max-width: initial; 
    height:100%;
    border:0.25rem solid #fff;
}

.hOuter, hOuter div {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hLeftParent {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: transparent;
    padding:0;
}

.hLeft1,
.hLeft2 {
    background: transparent;
    min-width:100%;
    height:50%;
    min-height:50%;
    display:table;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;

}

.hLeft1 span,
.hLeft2 span,
.hRight span {
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width:100%;
}


.hLeft1 {
    border-bottom:0.125rem solid #fff;
    height:30rem;
    min-height:30rem;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
}

.hLeft2 {
    border-top:0.125rem solid #fff;
    height:30rem;
    min-height:30rem;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat 0 0 / cover;    
}

.hOuter .hRight {
    background: #ccc;
    border-left:0.25rem solid #fff;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat center bottom / cover;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    display: table;
}

.hOuter .hRight span {
    background-color: rgba(91,91,91, 0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, not sure if I am understand your question correctly. You seem to have declared two different heights in your left containers. I tried removing the second declaration for both Left1 & Left2 and I think I got your desired effect.

```
.hLeft1 {
    border-bottom:0.125rem solid #fff;
    /*height:30rem;*/
    /*min-height:30rem;*/
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
}

.hLeft2 {
    border-top:0.125rem solid #fff;
    /*height:30rem;*/
    /*min-height:30rem;*/
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat 0 0 / cover;    
}
```

Comment: James, thanks for your help, when I remove the height from .hLeft1 and .hLeft2 the containers collapse and now they are simply high enough to fit the content (default behaviour). I need for each container to be half the height of its parent. Just like the effect on [HubSpot](http://www.hubspot.com)

Comment: No problem. Just to double check this is Not the result you are trying to achieve: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesvan/rshd93z5/embedded/result/). For me the boxes expand the height of the screen. I am currently on my surface, i can take a better look when I get home.

Comment: Yes that IS the effect I want. I did some testing and I created a new HTML file and added only the relevant code for the effect in it. I did the same with the CSS and connected the two files. No surprises as the both left images were still collapsing. So I copy/pasted the CSS from the JSFiddle with the cat pictures and, for reasons unknown to me, it worked! Apparently there is something wrong with my images. (works with cat pictures and not with my pictures).